# Repeating complex pattern with header and date (same day 6x). Header, incremented date (same day 6x)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Creating a meal tracker in onenote displaying layout from external excel.  Since no locked cells in one note and for ease of viewing, I am attempting to create in my excel the following pattern:

[image: Meal tracker]

Pattern is:

Text row 
Date row [same date for 6 rows]
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Text row 
Date [date incremented from set above] [same date for 6 rows]
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Date row 
Text row

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

##### FORMULA

```
=LET(
  _start, $G$1,    _days, $G$2,
  _text, {"Date","Time","Meal","Food Served"},
  _meals, {"Breakfast","Snack","Lunch","Snack","Dinner","Snack"},
  _col1, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE, INDEX(_text, 1)&","&
          (LAMBDA(x, SUBSTITUTE(REPT(TEXT(_start+x,"mm/dd/yyyy")&",",
          COUNTA(_meals))&",",",,",""))(SEQUENCE(_days,1,0,1)))),,","),
  _rows, _days*(COUNTA(_meals)+1),
  _col2, TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REPT(INDEX(_text,2)&REPT(",",COUNTA(_meals)+1),_days)&";",",;",""),,",",FALSE),
  _col3, TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REPT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, INDEX(_text, 3),_meals)&",",_days)&",",",,",""),";",",",FALSE),
  _col4, TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REPT(INDEX(_text,4)&REPT(",",COUNTA(_meals)+1),_days)&";",",;",""),,",",FALSE),
  HSTACK( _col1, _col2,_col3,_col4 )
  )
```

<kbd># of Days set to:    **6**</kbd>
[image]

<kbd># of Days set to:    **3**</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Conditional Formatting:** Rules</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Conditional Formatting:** Custom Formula for Headings Rows</kbd>
[image]

<kbd>**Conditional Formatting:** Custom Formula Non-Headings Rows</kbd>
[image]

##### Excel Functions Used

| [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) | [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) | [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) | [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[REPT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061)** | **[TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)** | **[COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)** | **[HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2)** |
| **[TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)** | **[SUBSTITUTE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)** | **[SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)** |  |